# Run same Js script twice or more on same webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm building a menu, which has tabs on a side and the relative contante on the other. When i mouse over one li element it shows the content of its relative li and hides any previous. 
The problems is that my theme loads the same menu twice, one mobile and one desktop, therefore when i call my template part, it also load the same code twice, therefore the same script that eventually doesn't work anymore.
Therefore I'm trying to find a solution that lets me run the same script twice or more on the same page; i've think that i could use a variable with an increment once it's run everytime, but doesn't work.
Js:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( this ($) ) {
$('#cbi-main-menu-left li').on("mouseover", function() {
     $("#" + $(this).data("menucbi")).show();
     $("#" + $(this).data("menucbi")).siblings().hide();
    });
});  
</script>
```

And i place this script inside the PHP template part i'm calling in the menu.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't put that javascript into the module, but more like into a separate javascript file (or an existing one) and as a real function and not a anonymous one.

So you could do:

```
$('#cbi-.....').on('mouseover', myCoolFunction);

function myCoolFunction() {
    $('#' ....).data("menucbi")).show();
    // the rest..
};
```

If you put this into the module it will kill the purpose of a reusable model, because you will overwrite the content or with jQuery and the mouseover event you will even add another event into the event chain, which will trigger the event twice on mouseover!

Comment: Thanks, I've tried but can't make it work, surely I'm doing something wrong here?  jQuery(document).ready(function( this ($) ) {
 $('#cbi-main-menu-left li').on('mouseover', cbiMegaMenu);

  function cbiMegaMenu() {
   $("#" + $(this).data("menucbi")).show();
   $("#" + $(this).data("menucbi")).siblings().hide();
  };
});